# What is the proper way to use mix-ins in C++ to fulfill interface contracts?

Tags: c++, interface, mixins, diamond-problem

I apologize in advance for the highly specific example.

Let's say I have an "interface" (purely abstract class) `Drawable` which requires an implementation of `virtual void draw()`, as well as `virtual float compute_z()`. Let's say `draw()` is supposed to draw some object on the screen, and let's say `compute_z()` is supposed to return a depth for the purposes of allowing a rendering engine to order draw commands (e.g. for early z rejection / reducing overdraw).

Let's say I also have a very common implementation of the `draw()` function, which is simply to store a texture and draw a quad on the screen, mapping the quad's vertices to the texture's vertices, and let's say I expose that common implementation through a mix-in class called `SpriteMixin`.

Let's say I also have a very common implementation of the `compute_z()` function which simply returns some static value (static in the sense that it does not change, rather than in one of the many other senses of the term), and I expose it through a mix-in class called `StaticZComputerMixin`.

Now let's say I want to create an object called `StaticSprite` which inherits the `Drawable` interface and implements the two functions through the two mixins.

Lastly, let's say that I *sometimes* want to be able to use these mixins *without* inheriting the entire `Drawable` interface. That is, it might be useful to be able to render a simple quad texture via a `SpriteMixin`, but not necessarily have to be able to compute a depth (or vice versa). Yet, at *other* times, I *do* want to inherit the whole interface, and in fact implement it via these mix-ins.

I believe have found *one* relatively simple solution. In particular, I believe that in order to use these mix-ins to fulfill the interface, they must inherit from the interface. However, since I don't *always* want to inherit from the interface, I have to use a little bit of template trickery. I am hesitant though; since there are two mixins, I have to use multiple virtual inheritance to "delegate the implementations to the sister mixin classes", as described [here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-delegate-to-sister):

```
class Drawable {
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
    virtual float compute_z() = 0;
};

template<typename base>
class SpriteMixin : public virtual base {
private:
    texture t;
public:
    SpriteMixin(texture t) : t(t) {}

    void draw() {
        // Draw t here...
    }
};

template<typename base>
class StaticZComputerMixin : public virtual base {
private:
    float z;
public:
    StaticZComputerMixin(float z) : z(z) {}

    float compute_z() {
        return this->z;
    }
};

class StaticSprite : public SpriteMixin<Drawable>, public StaticZComputerMixin<Drawable> {
public:
    StaticSprite(texture t, float z)
        : SpriteMixin<Drawable>(t), StaticZComputerMixin<Drawable>(z){}
};
```

Of course, if I wanted to *not* inherit the entire `Drawable` interface, I could do some basic additional template magic (like full template specialization) to support that.

I don't believe that there's necessarily something *wrong* with this. As far as I'm aware, such "sister delegations" are one of the motivating purposes of virtual inheritance. However, I've also heard that virtual inheritance is a "hacky" solution to the diamond problem (and this is essentially the diamond problem).

Is there a more proper solution to this problem?

**Edit:**

I now realize that I could also reverse the inheritance tree, i.e. I could have a templated `SpriteMixin` inherit from a templated `StaticZComputerMixin` which inherits from a `StaticSprite` which inherits from `Drawable`. However, this would require something like variadic expansion of template parameters to properly pass all of the constructor arguments up the hierarchy (sort of like `std::vector::emplace()`), since in this case you would have to be able to specify the parents of the mix-ins in a templated way, and those parents might have constructor parameters. From my understanding, these are the two most common mixin implementations in c++, as described [here](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/12/12/mixin-classes-yang-crtp/) (my former solution corresponds to the CRTP-minded solution). However, as Wikipedia states, "a mixin is a class that contains methods for use by other classes without having to be the parent class of those other classes", which suggests that the CRTP solution isn't *technically* a mixin implementation.

Is there a preferred solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this solves your problem entirely, but how about splitting up `Drawable` into two separate interfaces, like this?

```
class IDrawable {
public:
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

class IComputeZable {
public:
    virtual float compute_z() = 0;
};

class StaticZ : public IComputeZable
{
public:
    StaticZ(float z) : _z(z) {}

    virtual float compute_z() {return _z;}

private:
    const float _z;
};

class SpriteDrawable : public IDrawable {
public:
    SpriteDrawable(texture t) : _t(t) {}

    virtual void draw() {drawTexture(_t);}

private:
    texture _t;
};

class StaticZSpriteDrawable : public StaticZ, public SpriteDrawable
{
public:
   StaticZSpriteDrawable(float z, texture t) : StaticZ(z), SpriteDrawable(t) {}
};
```

That way any class-type can implement `IDrawable/compute_z()` or `IComputeZable/draw()`, or both, as it sees fit.

Comment: This nearly solves my problem, but I require an abstract base type which is capable of both `draw()` and `compute_z()` for my polymorphic needs. So one way or another, I need an interface somewhere with both of these virtual methods. However, I can still separate the interface into two, and then just have a third interface which inherits both of those separate interfaces. But that doesn't change the fact that I still need to use multiple virtual inheritance and templating to tell the mixins which interfaces to inherit depending on the use case.